# How to set up a gunicorn script (django)

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I use gunicorn to start my django app. For that I usually go into the directory where the manage.py file is located and then use this command:

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi --workers=2
```

that I got form the [official documentation](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html) (it's using a different settings file)

Now, I want to write a script that does that which I found [here](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html):

```
#!/bin/sh

GUNICORN=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
ROOT=/path/to/folder/with/manage.py
PID=/var/run/gunicorn.pid

#APP=main:application

if [ -f $PID ]; then rm $PID; fi

cd $ROOT
exec $GUNICORN -c $ROOT/ gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi --pid=$PID #$APP
```

But I get this

> usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
>
> gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app.wsgi

when I execute it. Any idea on how to write it so it will work?

And also, what is that PID ?

Thanks !

Comment: That is not a script that you run from the command line; it is, as that doc page explains, a script for [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/).

Comment: shouldn't it work anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's pretty simple, just create a file with (`sudo nano gunicorn.sh`)

```
cd /path/to/folder/with/manage.py/
exec gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi
```

and then execute it

```
./gunicorn.sh
```